# Listing files shows deleted items

Tags: java, android

After I delete a file from a folder with File.delete(), the return value is true, so the file is deleted. When I list the files from the folder, the deleted file doesn't appear.

So good so far. If I put my app into background, when I get back on, in on resume() function,  I list all the files from that directory, and the 'deleted' file appears.

I've tested it several times and I can't seem seem to figure out a logical reason. Any help guys?

Deleting the file:

```
boolean bDeleted = file.delete();
```

Listing the files:

```
 @Override
  public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     String[] list = fileIn.list(); //list contains the 'deleted' file after putting the app in background
  }
```

Comment: Post some code so that we can help you

Comment: is `bDeleted` `true`?

Comment: @Kevin Yes! Edited but I don't think code will help. Is a strange behaviour. The function returns true when i delete the file, the listing of the folder's files isn't showing the recently deleted file, so all good. But if i put my app in background, when i get back on, the listing shows the deleted file as if it wasn't deleted. And this occurs only when turning the app into background.

Comment: If you navigate to the folder the files were in are they deleted or are they still there?

Comment: what is `fileIn`, and what the method `list()` does? I think it caches previous file list somewhere

Comment: Solved it! The code was fine. The problem was that in the main activity, in OnResume(), some files we're copied so that's why the listing showed me the recently deleted file. Because the file was copied in OnResume of the activity and in the OnResume of the fragment the listing was called. Thank you all!

Comment: @user5076870 I suggest you delete this question as the problem was specific to your app, and this is not generally useful to others.  In fact, the root cause is in code you have not even posted so there is no way for anyone to answer this question.